# The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

Tags: asp.net

I am getting the following errors:

> "The remote server returned an error:
>   (400) Bad Request"
>
> "Requested time out"

sometimes when connecting to a host using a web service. If the XML returned is 5 kb then it is working fine, but if the size is 450kb or above it is displaying the error.

Below is my code as well as the config file that resides at the client system. We don't have access to the settings of the server.

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim fileName As String = Server.MapPath("capitaljobs2.xml")

        Dim client = New CapitalJobsService.DataServiceClient("WSHttpBinding_IDataService", "http://xyz/webservice.svc")


        Dim userAccount = New UserAccount()

        'replace here 
        Dim jobAdList = client.GetProviderJobs(userAccount)

        '## Needed only to create XML files - do not ucomment - will overwrite files 
        'if (jobAdList != null) 
        ' SerialiseJobAds(fileName, jobAdList); 

        '## Read new ads from Xml file 
        Dim capitalJobsList = DeserialiseJobdAds(fileName)
        UpdateProviderJobsFromXml(client, userAccount, capitalJobsList)              
        client.Close()
    End Sub

 Private Shared Function DeserialiseJobdAds(ByVal fileName As String) As CapitalJobsService.CapitalJobsList
        Dim capitalJobsList As CapitalJobsService.CapitalJobsList
        ' Deserialize the data and read it from the instance 
        If File.Exists(fileName) Then
            Dim fs = New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open)
            Dim reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(fs, New XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas())
            Dim ser2 = New DataContractSerializer(GetType(CapitalJobsList))
            capitalJobsList = DirectCast(ser2.ReadObject(reader, True), CapitalJobsList)
            reader.Close()
            fs.Close()
            Return capitalJobsList
        End If
        Return Nothing
    End Function
```

And the config file

```
 <system.web>
 <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="524288" />
  </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IDataService" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2000000" maxArrayLength="2000000" maxBytesPerRead="2000000" maxNameTableCharCount="2000000" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" establishSecurityContext="true"/>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://xyz/DataService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IDataService" contract="CapitalJobsService.IDataService" name="WSHttpBinding_IDataService">
                                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost"/>
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

I am using "Fiddler" to track the activities it is reading and terminating file like

> *** FIDDLER: RawDisplay truncated at 16384 characters. Right-click to
>   disable truncation. ***

But in config the number 16348 is not mentioned anywhere.

Can you figure out if the error is on client or server side? The settings above are on the client side.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you put four spaces before each line of code, it gets formatted as such, and your XML won't be eaten by the HTML sanitizer :)

Comment: your post isn't formatted properly, please re-format it.

Comment: Btw, I can guess that Fiddler error message is not related to your config, but to Fiddler's config. By default it won't display more than 16384 characters and you have to disable that setting.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have edited with re-format. Pls. check the posting.

Comment: I did what I could to "salvage" this post... I hope I didn't break anything I shouldn't...

Comment: The message titled "RawDisplay truncated" is shown by Fiddler itself.  If you do as it says, you can turn off the display truncation feature.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can increase the timeout of call like suggest in this thread
[Setting Timeout Value For .NET Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711311/setting-timeout-value-for-net-web-service/711360#711360)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but don't know where to do the changes as i have only control to client system not for Host as it is placed remotely.