# Setting Timeout value for Salesforce Web Service/API

Tags: asp.net, web-services, timeout, salesforce

The API for Salesforce is a web service, you set it up by downloading a WSDL file from Salesforce and adding the WSDL to your .NET project.

But I can't find anywhere to set the Timeout value.

Normally in a .NET Web Service there is a Timeout property for this (as [described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711311/setting-timeout-value-for-net-web-service)), but I can't seem to find one in this case.

Comment: Have you used Visual Studio or wsdl.exe to generate proxy classes for the Salesforce web service?

Comment: Yes, the proxy classes are there and I can use them to call the web service. But there is no Timeout property as far as I can tell.

Comment: What base class does your proxy class inherit from?  Normally the Timeout property comes from System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol

Comment: Proxy inherits from SoapHttpClientProtocol, which is a descendent of WebClientProtocol.I found the Timeout propery, right where it should have been. I dont know why I couldn't find it earlier ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having attached the WSDL to your .net App, you can configure the Timeout property on the proxy class like:

```
PartnerReference.SforceService partnerRef = new PartnerReference.SforceService();
partnerRef.Timeout = 30000;
partnerRef.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
partnerRef.Proxy = System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
partnerRef.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

PartnerReference.LoginResult loginResult = partnerRef.login("Name", "Password");
```

I'm fairly sure that this will work for the Enterprise WSDL, too...

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure I checked out the SforceService object and couldn't find the Timeout property earlier ... but you're right - its there.

Comment: @kiwipom I dont understand where do I add this in my application. I dont have the timeout property :s

Comment: @raym0nd I haven't done any Salesforce work for over 3 years! Sorry, you'll need to ask a fresh question...

Comment: I asked a question here but no replies yet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019359/increase-salesforce-webservice-timeout-in-net-application