# .NET WebService Timeout Exception

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, iis

I am getting the following exception when calling a web service operation in my .NET application:

> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest
>   request) at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest
>   request) at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] parameters) at
>   org.wvi.hrmgmt.HRManagementServiceserviceagent.LoadReducedTemplate(LoadReducedTemplateRequest
>   LoadReducedTemplateRequest) at
>   org.wvi.mgmt.hr._ServiceClient.UploadReducedTemplate()

Basically, a user uploads a file into the web server and the binary contents of this file is being passed as one of the input parameters when calling a web service operation. The size of the file is 1,397 KB and if I choose to process this file, I am getting the exception. Whereas, processing a file with a relatively smaller size, supposed 127 KB, gives a successful response.

I have done the below steps in order to solve the dillema:

1. Setting the web service timeout to infinite. -> Not getting an exception and any response
2. Adding Response.Close() -> Not getting any response
3. Editing the web.config in the IIS server and adding the following lines: -> Still getting the exception

   ```
   <system.web>
       <customErrors mode="Off"/>
   <httpRuntime executionTimeout="600" maxRequestLength="16384"/>
   <sessionState timeout="540"/>
   </system.web>
   ```

However, to no avail, I'm still getting the above exception. I am using a Javascript plugin called AjaxUpload from GitHub and I can't figure out whether they have file upload size limit. Besides, I have checked the file if it is being uploaded on the server and it does, therefore, the issue may not be because of that plugin.

Another issue is that I am getting the same exception when uploading the file after a period of time the web page has been opened. I surmise that this has something to do with session timeout so I added an additional line in my web.config file specifying the maximum timeout. Please advise me if I'm on the right track.

Are there additional settings I need to apply in my IIS server to make the operation successful? Otherwise, are there anything I am missing? If you have experienced this before, kindly inform me what to do.

Thank you so much,
Ralph

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to lot of proxy opened before. So I suggest you to delete Service.Reference.Config along with web service reference and add the service reference again and see whether it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to the previous answer, you may try setting up the execution time out on the proxy class , Refer this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711311/setting-timeout-value-for-net-web-service)

And you service call is performing a long running task you may prefer to have a lengthy time out for any webservice call by setting the timeout in proxy class as said before.