# Operation timed out error when downloading with WebClient

Tags: c#, http

I am getting Operation timed out exception .

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;

namespace Timer1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Timer t = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 420000); // 7 minutes

        }
        private static void TimerCallback(Object o)
        {


            string url = string.Empty;
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            url = @"http://myurl.com";
            client.DownloadString(url);


        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to increase timeout property ? Please help.

Comment: look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/711311/setting-timeout-value-for-net-web-service

Comment: thanks , checked it , answers mention to increase timeout property but there is no timeout property for WebClient object.

Comment: There is a WebClient.Timeout. See my answer.

Comment: Look at this Answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601861/set-timeout-for-webclient-downloadfile

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest answer is to use `client.Timeout = 420000` ([WebRequest.Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.timeout.aspx)), but if you are going to do that with a timer, you might as well try an asynchronous version. Something along the lines of [Set timeout for webClient.DownloadFile()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601861/set-timeout-for-webclient-downloadfile)

Comment: does the Timeout property exist for WebClient ?

Comment: I added a link to the MSDN doc on the property.

Comment: m.hasan, look at the `WebRequest.Timout` property click on the link and I think that this will answer the question for you