# Set a time limit on a response from a web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

If I call a web service ...

```
Service1 myWebService = new Service1();
int NewTotal = myWebService.CurrentBreakdowns(6);
```

How can I set a time limit on getting a response from the web service. I want to give it 30 seconds to respond and, if a response is not received, carry on and show a 'did not receive a timely response' message.

Comment: Did you use "Add Service Reference", or the legacy "Add Web Reference"?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the timeout as follows

```
localhost.Service1 service = new localhost.Service1();
service.Timeout = 30000;
```

where **Timeout** Indicates the time an XML Web service client waits for the reply to a synchronous XML Web service request to arrive (in milliseconds).

You can also try as suggested  in the following post in SO

- [Setting Timeout Value For .NET Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/711360/1012641)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line under your `<system.web>` in your web.config:

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="30"/>
```

Wrap your service call in a `try/catch` block and handle the exception.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ... but I only want to restrict the execution to 30 seconds for just calling that web service. I am quite happy with the default executionTimeout for everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Hi bro I gave a time limit on client with this code;

firstly create service proxy in class

`private BussinessAdapter serviceProxy = null;`

in constructer assign a new adapter with this:

`serviceProxy = new BussinessAdapter();`

And you can set the time with this code in functions;

`serviceProxy.Timeout=3000000; //to 50 min I gave`

... and you need to sync with web service time out time my web service has the same time limit.