# How to set a timeout on a SOAP call in MS .Net 4.5 using C#

Tags: c#, soap, timeout

I need to account for extremely slow responses from a SOAP server. I have added the service in C# language using Visual Studio 2012 and I really would like to be able to easily set a timeout value on the service object and handle a suitably named exception when a response is not received within that time frame.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.services2.soapwebrequest.timeout.aspx .

In short, use the SoapWebRequest's Timeout property.

Comment: sorry, I'm new to C#. I have a `ApplicationClient` type which I instantiate to invoke the service. On which object exactly should I set this property?

Comment: What is the base class of `ApplicationClient`? How do you obtain an instance of `ApplicationClient`?

Comment: One of the base classes is `System.ServiceModel.ClientBase` which is in `Reference.cs` source file and the other is the service reference which has been created by the wizard.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924831(v=vs.110).aspx might help you then. If you are not using WCF in a fashion similar to the one described there, http://stackoverflow.com/a/711360/4134826 should help.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is deprecated,
Here's how you set the timeout in newer .NET versions:

```
client.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
```

Resource:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/configuring-timeout-values-on-a-binding